# Why the following does not work for autowired

Tags: spring

I have a class like

```
class A {
      @Autowired
      B b;
}

A a = new A()
```

I found `b` is not autowired

I already did `<context:component-scan base-package="*">`, anything else missing?

Comment: is there any annotation on class B definition ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to get the bean from a bean factory, instead of creating an instance directly.

For example, here's how to do it with annotations. First, you need to add a bit more to your declaration of your class:

```
// Annotate to declare this as a bean, not just a POJO
@Component
class A {
    @Autowired
    B b;
}
```

Next, you do this *once per application*:

```
AnnotationConfigApplicationContext factory =
        new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext();
factory.register(A.class);
factory.register(B.class);
// Plus any other classes to register, or use scan(packages...) method
factory.refresh();
```

Finally, you can now get instances of the bean:

```
// Instead of: new A()
A a = factory.getBean(A.class);
```

Comment: I note that you're using XML configuration too. That's fine; just get the application context (which is also the bean factory) and use its `getBean` method(s).

Answer (score 3):

Spring will only autowire the `A` object if Spring instantiates it as a bean.  if you instantiate your own, Spring knows nothing about it, so nothing gets autowired.